# One class, two objects and strange behaviour with class data

Tags: c++, class

I looked at similar titles in this site, but still could not find the answer. So maybe someone can clarify it for me.

Lets say I have:

```
// Example class
class CFirst
{
 public:
    CFirst{ }
    virtual ~CFirst{ }
    int i;
    float y;
};

// Other class methods looks like this
.........
CFirst *data = new CFirst();
data->i = 10;
data->y = 10.10;

if (data != NULL)
{
    delete data; 
    data = NULL;
}

CFirst *data1 = new CFirst();
std::cout<<data1->i<<std::endl;
............
```

Now ques what. data1->i shows 10.
How is that possible..
PS: It's just an example.

Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data1->i
```

is not initialized and it can show any value for that matter.

```
CFirst *data = new CFirst();
data->i = 10;
data->y = 10.10;
```

When you did the above steps for `data` you created a new CFirst object on the dynamic memory area(heap/Freestore) and assigned values to members `i` and `y` of `CFirst` object.

For `data` object you just created the object on dynamic memory area by,

```
CFirst *data1 = new CFirst();
```

You did not initialize them, Uninitialized variables can contain anything valid numbers or even garbage values, Just that by chance `data->i` contains `10`, mind you there is no specific reason it contains `10`, it can contain anything.

It's a bad idea to use UnInitialized member variables, One should ideally initialize the member variables in **Initializer List**.

```
CFirst(int p, float q):i(p),y(q)
{ 

}
```

Comment: Ah I see now. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Now ques what. data1->i shows 10. How is that possible.. PS: It's just an example.

That is just garbage that happens to be `10`.

And now if you ask what compiler does here? Well, it may be that the compiler creates the second object in the same memory where previous object was created. And that memory hasn't been erased by anything yet, in between deletion of the first object and creation of the second object. There is no such guarantee, though.

In any case, such details as to where which object is created, depends on the compiler strategy which could by anything. So your code shouldn't assume any such thing.

Answer (score 2):

You have an empty constructor. This means that every data member gets default initialized, **except built-in types**.

So `data1->i` is uninitialized and has a garbage value. That garbage value seems to be the previous data, `10`.

Please note that it could have been `10`, `0` or even `-1295812`.